# How can I send Super from my Mac to my Emacs instance?

Tags: keymap, osx, x11

I run emacs in two ways: One as a Mac OS X executable, built from source, and the other as a Linux executable using the Lucid toolkit, in daemon mode, connected to using a graphical emacscient using XQuartz on my mac laptop.

My base configuration is currently Emacs Prelude, and it defines a set of key chords that use a <kbd>Super</kbd> key, in addition to some <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> chords. However, I cannot figure out how to send a <kbd>Super</kbd> chord at all. This is true both on my OSX build and on my emacsclient/XQuartz setup. <kbd>Command</kbd> sends Meta, <kbd>Option</kbd> just sends literal keys (in the OSX way, it emits a subset of the extended Unicode space) and obviously <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> do their usual thing.

So, how do I send super-prefixed key chords to my Emacs?

Answer (score 7):

You can apply a super modifier with `C-x @ s`.  So to type <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, you woule press `C-x @ s z`.  If you find the `C-x @ s` combo too cumbersome, then you can bind it to something easier to type.  Here is an example of binding it to `C-]`:

```el
;; Turn `C-]' into a sticky "super" modifier.
(define-key local-function-key-map [?\C-\]] 'event-apply-super-modifier)
;; Move the global binding for C-] to C-s-]
(define-key global-map [?\C-\s-\]] (lookup-key global-map [?\C-\]] t))
(define-key global-map [?\C-\]] nil)
```

Since `C-]` is most likely already bound to something (`abort-recursive-edit` by default), I also move whatever is bound to `C-]` in the global map to `C-s-]`.  You can then invoke `abort-recursive-edit` when needed by typing `C-]` twice.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at the various `ns-*-modifier`, like `ns-alternate-modifier` (for <kbd>Option</kbd>) or `ns-command-modifier` (for <kbd>Command</kbd>). They allow to map the native OSX keys to arbitrary modifiers. Note that there exists a `ns-function-modifier` which is quite handy for laptops.

That should solve the native OSX Emacs part.

As for XQuartz, without testing at all, I would assume that you might get away with some `xmodmap` invocation, along the line of `xmodmap -e 'add Mod2 = Super_L Super_R'`

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging, I located [this page by Xah Lee](http://xahlee.info/kbd/Mac_OS_X_keymapping_keybinding_tools.html).

The cause of your problem is that your keyboard settings in OSX are not set for any key to send <kbd>Super</kbd>. In order to send <kbd>Super</kbd>, you need to change that. The document linked above has directions for doing so.

Comment: Please include a summary of what to do, as such a link may break.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html) tells you what to do. The following is the summary of what to do:

### Create Super and Hyper Keys on MacOS

```el
;; set keys for Apple keyboard, for emacs in OS X
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta) ; make cmd key do Meta
(setq mac-option-modifier 'super) ; make opt key do Super
(setq mac-control-modifier 'control) ; make Control key do Control
(setq ns-function-modifier 'hyper)  ; make Fn key do Hyper
```

Note: if you set <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, some of their Mac function remains. For example, <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> still do switch app, and <kbd>Fn</kbd> key can still be used as the modifier for multimedia keys.